# how to change sending e-mail address newsletter

Tags: magento2, email-templates, newsletter

I have configure the sending newslatter from my basic store email address, e.g. sales@store.com

[image]

After confirm sending the newsletter, the magento sends from the email address from the server (eg. user@myserverprovider.com) no from my email.

therefore, all newsletter sent to clients do not reach.

How to solve this to set up shipping directly from my email account?

Answer (score 1):

You should change below configuration :

Go to

> Admin => Stores => Configuration => General => Store Email Addresses

please review attached screenshot for changes

[image]

Comment: If above answer working for you please accept, so another use same